login google use next auth with custom url redirect
I have a case, where when logging in to google using next auth. login is successful but does not enter the redirected page because the url needs to add a user, for example http://localhost:3000/user/api/auth/callback/google?state=****. If you add a user like this then the page automatically goes to the customized page. How can I add /user in next auth with google?
this code
.env
NEXT_PUBLIC_URL=secret
NEXT_PUBLIC_UPLOAD=secret
NEXT_PUBLIC_IMG=https:secret
NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYMENT=https:secret
NEXT_PUBLIC_KEY=secret
NODE_ENV=production
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=secret
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=secret
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=secret

[...nextauth].ts
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { postData } from '@/utils/fetch'; // Utility untuk melakukan request POST
import { config } from '@/configs'; // Config untuk Google dan secret NextAuth

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt', // Menggunakan JWT sebagai strategy session
    },
    secret: config.NEXTAUTH_SECRET, // Menggunakan secret dari config
    providers: [
        // Provider untuk login dengan email dan password menggunakan Credentials
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: 'next-auth-login',
            name: 'Credentials',
            credentials: {},
            async authorize(credentials: any) {
                try {
                    const { email, password } = credentials as {
                        email: string,
                        password: string
                    };
                    // Request login ke API backend
                    const { data } = await postData('/auth/login', {
                        email: email,
                        password: password,
                        login_via: 'EMAIL'
                    });

                    
                    if(data?.data?.token){
                        return {
                            id: data?.data?.user?.id,
                            name: data?.data?.user?.name,
                            email: data?.data?.user?.email,
                            username: data?.data?.user?.username,
                            avatar: data?.data?.user?.avatar,
                            image: data?.data?.user?.avatar,
                            token: data?.data?.token
                        };
                    }else{
                        throw new Error('Token Not Found')
                    }
                } catch (error: any) {
                    // Menangkap error dan melempar kembali untuk ditampilkan
                    throw new Error(error?.response?.data?.message || 'Login failed');
                }
            }
        }),
        // Provider Google untuk login menggunakan Google
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: config.GOOGLE_ID as string,
            clientSecret: config.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    redirect_uri: `${config.NEXTAUTH_URL}/user/api/auth/callback/google`
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    cookies: {
        sessionToken: {
            name: 'next-auth.session-token',
            options: {
                path: '/',
                httpOnly: true,
                sameSite: 'lax',
                secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
            },
        },
    },
    
    // Custom halaman auth
    pages: {
        signIn: '/user/auth/login',
        error: '/user/auth/error', // Halaman error jika ada masalah
    },
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    callbacks: {
        // Menambahkan data ke token JWT
        async jwt({ token, user, account }: any) {
            if(account?.provider === 'google'){
                try {
                    const payload = {
                        email: token.email,
                        login_via: 'GOOGLE'
                    }
    
                    const {data} = await postData('/auth/login-google', {
                        ...payload,
                        google_token: account?.id_token
                    })
    
                    if(data?.data?.user?.token){
                        
                        token.id = data?.data?.user?.user_data?.id
                        token.name = data?.data?.user?.user_data?.name
                        token.email = data?.data?.user?.user_data?.email
                        token.username = data?.data?.user?.user_data?.username
                        token.avatar = data?.data?.user?.user_data?.avatar
                        token.image = data?.data?.user?.user_data?.avatar
                        token.token = data?.data?.user?.token
                    }else{
                        throw new Error('Failed to Retrieve')
                    }
                } catch (error: any) {
                    throw new Error(error?.response?.data?.message || 'Login failed');
                }
            }else if(user) {
                token.id = user.id;
                token.name = user.name;
                token.email = user.email;
                token.username = user.username;
                token.avatar = user.avatar;
                token.image = user.avatar
                token.token = user.token; // Menyimpan token ke JWT
            }
            console.log('Token', token)
            return token;
        },

        // Menyimpan data dari JWT ke session
        async session({ session, token }: any) {
            session.id = token.id;
            session.name = token.name;
            session.email = token.email;
            session.username = token.username;
            session.avatar = token.avatar;
            session.image = token.avatar
            session.token = token.token; // Menyimpan token ke session
            // console.log(session, 'Session +++++')
            return session;
        }
    }
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
export { authOptions }


login.tsx
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

//* component
import FormLabel from '@/components/core/Label';
import AuthHeading from '@/components/auth/Heading';
import { showMessage } from '@/components/core/Alert/ShowMessage';

//* utils
import { getData, postData } from '../../../../../utils/fetch';

//* store
import { userLogin } from '../../../../../store/auth/actions';

//* image
import Button from '@/components/core/Button';
import eyeOff from '../../../../public/assets/images/eye-off.svg';
import eye from '../../../../public/assets/images/eyeOn.svg';
import { setCookie } from 'cookies-next';
import AuthInput from '@/components/core/AuthInput';
import { EyeIcon } from '@/components/icon/eyes';
import { EyeOff } from '@/components/icon/eye-off-icon';
import Spinner from '@/components/core/spinner';
import GoogleIcon from '@/components/icon/google';
import { signInWithPopup, onAuthStateChanged, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth'
import { auth } from '@/firebase'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react'

const LoginContent = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {t} = useTranslation()

    const subsciption: any = useSelector((state: any) => state.auth)

    const [form, setForm] = useState({ email: '', password: '', rememberMe: false, login_via: 'EMAIL' });
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const handleChangeInput = (e: any) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        if (name === 'rememberMe') {
            setForm({ ...form, [name]: form.rememberMe ? false : true });
        } else {
            setForm({ ...form, [name]: value });
        }
    };

    // console.log(subsciption)

    const handleShowPassword = () => {
        setVisible(visible ? false : true);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { email, password, rememberMe } = form;
        if (!email || !password) {
            showMessage(`${email === '' ? 'Email' : ''} ${email === '' && password === '' ? 'and' : ''} ${password === '' ? 'Password' : ''} required`, 'error');
        } else {
            try {
                setIsLoading(true);
                await signIn('next-auth-login', {
                    redirect: false,
                    email,
                    password,
                    callbackUrl: 'https://maxbase.xyz/user'
                })
                // const { data } = await postData('/auth/login', form);
                // // console.log(data)
                // const isDefault = data.user.is_default;
                // if (isDefault) {
                //     dispatch(userLogin({ is_default: data.user.is_default, user: data.user }));
                //     router.push('/user/auth/password-default');
                // } else {
                //     dispatch(userLogin({ token: data.token, rememberMe, user: data.user }));
                //     setCookie('token', data.token);
                //     showMessage(`${t('Login successfully')}`);
                //     // await postData(`/subscription/activate/${subsciption?.subscription.id}`, {})
                    // setIsLoading(false);
                    router.push('/user')
                // }
                setIsLoading(false);
            } catch (error: any) {
                setIsLoading(false);
                showMessage(error?.response?.data.message, 'error');
            }
        }
    };

    const googleSignIn = async () => {
        let provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
        provider.addScope('email')
        provider.setCustomParameters({prompt: 'select_account'})

        signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then(async (result: any) => {
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result)
            const token = credential?.idToken
            const user = result?.user.providerData.map((item: any) => item?.email)
            // console.log(token)
            const {data} = await postData('/auth/login-google', {
                email: user.join(''),
                login_via: 'GOOGLE',
                google_token: token
            })
            dispatch(userLogin({ token: data.user.token, user: data.user.user_data }));
            setCookie('token', data.user.token);
            // // await postData(`/subscription/activate/${subsciption?.subscription.id}`, {})
            showMessage(`${t('Login successfully')}`);
            router.push('/user')
        }).catch((error: any) => {
            console.log(error?.response?.data.message)
            // if(error.code === 'auth/popup-closed-by-user'){
            //     // showMessage('Google Sign In Cancelled', 'error')
            // }else{
            //     showMessage('This Google need register', 'error')
            // }
        })
    }

    const handleGoogleSubmit = async () => {
        try {
            // await googleSignIn();
            signIn('google', {callbackUrl: '/user'})
            // router.push('/')
        } catch (error: any) {
            // Handle kesalahan autentikasi atau redireksi
            showMessage(error?.response?.data?.message, 'error');
        }        
    }

    return (
        <section className='w-96 z-20 sm:w-[420px] sm:bg-white sm:drop-shadow sm:rounded-md p-4 sm:p-8'>
            <div className="flex flex-col">
                <div className="text-center">
                    <Link href={'./login'} className="text-2xl font-bold flex gap-2 items-center justify-center">
                        <img className="inline h-[40px] ltr:-ml-1 rtl:-mr-1" src="/logo-2.png" alt="logo" />
                        {/* <div className="">PROFILIX</div> */}
                    </Link>
                    <div className="italic text-base text-zinc-600 mt-3">Login to dashboard</div>
                </div>
                <form className="mt-7" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="">
                        <label htmlFor="email" className='font-semibold text-zinc-700'>Email</label>
                        <AuthInput 
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        type="email"
                        className="form-input rounded-md py-2.5"
                        placeholder="Enter Email"
                        value={form.email}
                        onChange={handleChangeInput}
                        disabled={isLoading}
                            />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-4">
                        <div className="w-full flex justify-between items-center">
                            <label htmlFor="password" className='font-semibold text-zinc-700'>Password</label>
                            <Link href={'./forgot-password'} className="text-xs text-primary -mt-2">Forgot password?</Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="relative">
                            <AuthInput 
                            id="password"
                            name="password"
                            type={visible ? 'text' : 'password'}
                            className="form-input rounded-md py-2.5"
                            placeholder="Enter Password"
                            value={form.password}
                            onChange={handleChangeInput}
                            disabled={isLoading}
                            />
                            <div className="absolute right-0 top-[30%] bottom-0 mr-3">
                                {visible ? (
                                    <EyeOff width={20} height={20} className='opacity-60 cursor-pointer' 
                                    onClick={() => setVisible(false)}/>
                                    ) : (
                                    <EyeIcon width={20} height={20} className='opacity-60 cursor-pointer' 
                                    onClick={() => setVisible(true)}/>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="text-zinc-600 text-center mt-3 sm:text-base">{`Don't have any account?`} <Link href='./register' className='font-semibold text-primary underline'>Register</Link></div>
                    <button type={`${isLoading ? 'button' : 'submit'}`} className={`mt-3 inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 font-semibold leading-none rounded outline-none transition duration-300 ease-in-out focus:outline-none focus:shadow focus:ring-1 focus:ring-accent-700 bg-primary text-light text-white text-base border border-transparent hover:bg-[#41C9E2] px-5 py-0 h-12 w-full ${isLoading && 'cursor-not-allowed'}`}>
                    {!isLoading ? 'Login' : (<Spinner />)}
                    </button>
                </form>
                <div className="flex items-center w-full gap-1 mt-5">
                    <div className="flex flex-1 border-b border-b-zinc-300"></div>
                    <div className="flex">Or</div>
                    <div className="flex flex-1 border-b border-b-zinc-300"></div>
                </div>
                <div 
                    className='border mt-5 flex items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 rounded outline-none px-5 py-0 h-12 w-full cursor-pointer'
                    onClick={handleGoogleSubmit}
                >
                    <div>
                        <GoogleIcon/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default LoginContent;

I want to be able to enter by adding /user to the url. because by doing so the page automatically redirects according to the destination
